# Retrieving data from a BINARY column in MySQL and converting it to Base64 in PHP

Tags: php, mysql, binary, base64

So I have a BINARY(255) field in MySQL, and I want to store a Base64 string in it and retrieve it as needed using PHP.

I'm storing the data using
'UPDATE table SET bindata=0x'.bin2hex(base64_decode($b64));

Which seems to be working fine, at any rate, there is a value going into the database.  But I can't figure out how to get my original base64 string back.  I've tried using base64_encode on the SELECT results, using HEX(bindata) and then running hex2bin and base64_encode.  Neither seems to work.

If the base64 string, once converted into binary, has a bunch of zeros at the end, that's fine.

Comment: Did you try to use MySQLs [FROM_BASE64()](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/string-functions.html#function_from-base64) and [TO_BASE64()](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/string-functions.html#function_to-base64)?

Comment: @PaulSpiegel They don't seem to work in my version of MySQL.

Answer (score 0):

I would store the value this way:

```
$sql = "UPDATE table SET bindata=?";
$stmt = $pdo->prepare($sql);
```

Pass as your query parameter the result of `base64_decode($b64)`. It's okay to pass a binary string this way.

```
$stmt->execute([base64_decode($b64)]);
```

When you fetch the binary string from the database, query it like this:

```
$sql = "SELECT bindata FROM table ...";
$stmt = $pdo->prepare($sql);
$stmt->execute();
```

It's okay to fetch a binary string. After you fetch that into a result row, you can re-encode it.

```
while ($row = $stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)) {
    echo base64_encode($row['bindata']);
}
```